# Ionic: get individual value of JSON response data on success

Tags: json, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*. I have call web service from `$http` post method its working fine and get response on success like

`{status: "true", msg: "success"}`

What i need is to get only status value from response as i have to redirect on the basis of json status field.   If status value is true it get redirect to home page or else login page. I have tried to get value like

```
 .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data[0].status);

    })
```

its alert undefined.Please help me to get value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a `json` object having 2 values. Your response is in `data` varibale. So just need to put `data.status`

So In your case, code should be:

```
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data.status);
    })
```

Comment: Glad to know that it works for you. Please mark it as useful, so others can also use this...

Comment: Yeah,  i really want to,  but i can't because my reputation is less than 15. But i really thank you a lot for your kind help.